# Avoid the increment in the auto-increment value with ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: mysql

So I want to insert a new row but after checking, it doesn't already exist.

My table is quite simple;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table
(
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pl VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    num1 INT NOT NULL,
    num2 INT NOT NULL, 
    num3 INT NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (pl)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So I changed the values to something simple for convenience.

I tried doing `INSERT INTO table(pl, num1, num2, num3) VALUES(val,0,0,0) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE pl=pl;`
but the above still enters the record cause of the auto increment field.

I also tried doing the same but instead of `ON DUPLICATE`, `INSERT IGNORE INTO`but I got the same result.

So is there any way to insert the row only if the primary key doesn't exist and if it does do nothing? (right now a new identical row gets created where the increment is +1

Comment: You can add [UNIQUE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)  constraint while creating the table to any of your column or multiple columns.

Comment: So you mean preventing the insert by throwing an error?

Comment: You can catch the error. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449540/php-detect-mysql-update-insertion-failure-due-to-violated-unique-constraint)

Comment: Yeah I know I catch the error, but I suppose there is a better way of doing this than just throwing and catching the error, you know seems kinda unprofessional. Am just trying to improve efficiency otherwise I could select and then update on empty row.

Comment: You right, However this constraint will guarantee that none of your records will be duplicate.

Comment: Indeed valid point, most probably I will add that in my primary key regardless of the method I end up using on the insert, thanks