# Prevent Multiple INSERT in MySQL from API

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL MyISAM Table "transaction".

Schema is similar to:

```
+-----+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id  | amount | duplication_check |        date         |
+-----+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 123 |     80 |         123456789 | 2017-06-05 11:12:23 |
| 124 |     80 |         123456788 | 2017-06-05 11:12:23 |
+-----+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

`duplication_check` can be empty/null but if it is passed from a script (for example from an API call) my PHP code performs a simple check:

```
SELECT id FROM transaction WHERE duplication_check == 'passed_from_external'.
```

If this returns a result, of course the transaction failed.

Now, I have an Android app developed myself that uses - when submit a transaction via API - this `duplication_check` (I generate it with a `time()` function).

When the smartphone lose the connection, I can read in the API log (another table to log the API call) 2 or 3 times in different seconds that the API called my server 2-3 times, with same duplication code.

Unfortunately, the `INSERT` call is done three times. But, from a PHP test, I cannot replicate the bug (following call with same duplication_check are failed).

API log example (note the 3 different dates):

```
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
| id_api | amount | duplication_check |        date         |
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
|    123 |     80 | AAAAAAA           | 2017-06-05 11:12:23 |
|    124 |     80 | AAAAAAA           | 2017-06-05 11:12:25 |
|    125 |     80 | AAAAAAA           | 2017-06-05 11:12:27 |
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Transaction result (note the 3 same dates, next to the API Log):

```
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
|   id   | amount | duplication_check |        date         |
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
| 123111 |     80 | AAAAAAA           | 2017-06-05 11:12:28 |
| 124112 |     80 | AAAAAAA           | 2017-06-05 11:12:28 |
| 125113 |     80 | AAAAAAA           | 2017-06-05 11:12:28 |
+--------+--------+-------------------+---------------------+
```

Probably, I need to edit the Android app to block multiple call, but, is this possibly a multiple `INSERT` into a table and is it possible to prevent them?

Comment: Why don´t you make a UNIQUE index with your duplication_check row? This will prevent to write it more than once

Comment: @nacho can I edit the table adding the UNIQUE and insert a "random" selected unique code?

Comment: You´ll need a UNIQUE and NULL column, so when you don´t have any value the null is admited (and don´t generates a duplicated value). And yes, you can ALTER (or edit) the table and ADD (or modify) your column with a random selected unique code.

Comment: OK. If my "theory" is right, the UNIQUE prevent the write more than one time also in the case which database perform multiple INSERT at once?

Comment: Yes, your "theory" is right

Comment: Query should be SELECT id FROM transaction WHERE duplication_check = 'passed_from_external'.  (Single equal to symbol in SQL query).

Comment: Create a unique key constraint on "duplicate check" column and throw error in ur php code .                                                                             
if( mysql_errno() == 1062) {
<br/>    // Duplicate key
<br/>} Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8449540/php-detect-mysql-update-insertion-failure-due-to-violated-unique-constraint

Comment: @nacho thank you. Seems that I solved my issue. If you publish your solution as answer, I can approve it. Thank you!

Comment: @sineverba Thank you. I did copy & paste over the answer so you can approve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don´t you make a UNIQUE index with your duplication_check row? This will prevent to write it more than once. You´ll need a UNIQUE and NULL column, so when you don´t have any value the null is admited (and don´t generates a duplicated value). And yes, you can ALTER (or edit) the table and ADD (or modify) your column with a random selected unique code.